# Primefaces cascadeSelect inside column in datatable

Tags: button, datatable, primefaces

why cascadeSelect desables buttons ? if i use selectOneMenu it works well.
in this example i removed others columns to simplify:

```
 <p:accordionPanel id="infoMF">
     <p:tab id="mainInfo" title = "Equipment Information"> 
            <p:dataTable id="mainInfoTab" var="ecnEquipment" value="#{main.equipment.templateEqpItems}" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250" style="font-size:10px">
            
                <p:column headerText="ConstructType" style="text-align:center;width:0.2rem;font-size:10px;">                        
                    
                    <p:cascadeSelect styleClass="custom-filter" value="#{ecnEquipment.constructType}"  >
                      <f:selectItems value="#{list.listConstructType}" />   
                      <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@this"/>                                                  
                    </p:cascadeSelect>                              
                                    
                </p:column>                                     
            </p:dataTable>
            <p:toolbar>
            <p:toolbarGroup >
            
                <p:selectOneMenu 
                    label="Choose an equipment for deleting"
                    value="#{main.eqpToRemove}" 
                    immediate="true">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{main.listEqpExisting}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>                              
                 
                 <p:commandButton id="delBtn" icon="pi pi-trash"
                  action="#{main.deleteEquipment}" process="@this mainInfo"
                  update="mainInfo" styleClass="ui-button-danger"/>
                  
                  <p:tooltip value="Remove the selected equipment" for="delBtn"  />
                  <p:tooltip value="add an equipment" for="addBtn"  />
                  <p:tooltip value="select an equipment to remove" for="listToRemoveFrom"  /> 
                  <p:tooltip value="select a type for the equipment to add" for="listTypeEquipment"  />                         
            
                </p:toolbarGroup>               
            </p:toolbar>
            
        </p:tab>
 </p:accordionPanel>
```

there is no error in consol. i'am using java 8

Comment: When i remove the value from the cascadeSelect it works a bit better, only the selectOneMenu of the button remains not working :(

Comment: problem resolved by removing the process of the button process="@this mainInfo"